# How can I fill this dictionary faster?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, performance, dictionary, machine-learning

I am trying to make a dictionary that contains the prediction results from my machine learning model. I was hoping anyone have any suggestions on how to create this dictionary faster?

The format of the dictionary looks like this:

```
{'modelVersion': 2,
 'predictionDate': '2020-03-09',
 'users': 
[
    userId: 1111
    predictionScore: 0.72
    features:{
        "feature1":{
            value:1
            shap:2
        },
        "feature2":{
            value:2
            shap:3
        },
        ...
    },

],
[
    userId: 2222
    predictionScore: 0.72
    features:{
        "feature1":{
            value:1
            shap:2
        },
        "feature2":{
            value:2
            shap:3
        },
        ...
    }, 
],
...
]
}
```

This is my code so far, but it is too slow. Does anyone have any suggestions on how this code could be faster? I have 70 features and 500000 users, so payload["users"] will contain a list of 500000 user dicts where each of these have 70 features.

```
        payload = {}
        payload["modelVersion"] = 2
        payload["predictionDate"] = "2020-03-09"

        users = [None] * len(userIds) #userIds is a list of userIds
        featureNames = x_data.columns.tolist() #x_data is a pandas dataframe with features for each user

        for i, userId in enumerate(userIds):
            shapValues = shap_values_XGB[i].tolist() #List of shap values for user
            featureValues = x_data.iloc[i].tolist() #List of feature values for user

            features = pd.DataFrame(
                {"features": featureNames, "shap": shapValues, "value": featureValues})

            features = features.set_index('features').T.to_dict()

            user = {
                "userId": userId,
                "predictionScore": Y_prob[i].item(),
                "features": features
            }

            users[i] = user


        payload["users"] = users
```

Comment: See that you are creating a datafame here using ` features = pd.DataFrame(`
                `{"features": featureNames, "shap": shapValues, "value": featureValues})`  Can you try running your code without the piece to see if it runs any quicker? If it does then consider storing the feature names inside a list instead of `pandas dataframe`

Comment: Thank you, it made it 20 times faster to remove pandas dataframe

Answer (score 0):

I replaced this

```
features = pd.DataFrame({"features": featureNames, "shap": shapValues, "value": featureValues})

features = features.set_index('features').T.to_dict()
```

with this:

```
features = [featureNames, shap, featureValues]
featuresT = list(map(list, zip(*features)))
features = {item[0]: {"shap":item[1:2][0],"value":item[2:3][0]} for item in featuresT}
```

It made it 20 times faster :)